# How to create Json Response with append child object to each it's parent object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, web, asp.net-web-api2

```
 Table1:    [Building]([ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
            [BuildingCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
            [RoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,  )
```

Second table child table design is like

```
  Table2: [Role](
        [RoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](max) NULL)
```

Now, I want Response from is like:

```
BuildingCode1
            {
               RoleId:16C6BEA4-421A-4718-8B85-090FC2FD8BCF
               Name:Role Name 1
            },
BuildingCode2  
            {
               RoleId:2HJ44A4-621A-A718-8B85-P90FC2FD8BCF
               Name:Role Name 2
            },
BuildingCode3  
            {
               RoleId:KJL34J8-621A-A718-8B85-3FH39DKF48
               Name:Role Name 3
            }
```

For each Building code in table 1 get relevant Roleid Detail from table 2(Role). Please help How can I get this kind of response. Thanks in Advance
For this I Created 2 classes

```
  public class BCode_Role
        {
            public RoleTable[] BuildingCode { get; set; }
            public byte Status { get; set; }
        }

     public class RoleTable
        { 
            public Guid RoleID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

and method for return json is

```
public Bcode_Role BuldingDetail()
    {
        var result = new BuildingCode_Role();
        var dbBuildingCods = _context.Building.Select(x => x.Code);
        var dbRoles = _context.Role;
        var apiModels = dbRoles.Select(x => new RoleTable {RoleID= x.ID, Name = x.Name }).ToArray();
        result.BuildingCode = apiModels;
        return result;
    }
```

Form this i get This Json Output

```
{
    "buildingCode": [
        {
            "roleID": "0f752579-57cc-4266-a4b4-4759af97525e",
            "name": "Role 2"
        },
        {
            "roleID": "1914a479-cb75-48b9-b5c3-6792acfba7b3",
            "name": "Role 1"
        },
        {
            "roleID": "3bc21132-079d-4ab9-b9f5-fe2428a281f1",
            "name": "Role 3"
        }
    ],
    "status": 0
}
```

but actually I want

```
{
       "buildingCode1": {
            "roleID": "0f752579-57cc-4266-a4b4-4759af97525e",
            "name": "Role 2"
                        },
     "buildingCode"2: {
            "roleID": "1914a479-cb75-48b9-b5c3-6792acfba7b3",
            "name": "Role 1"
                      },
      "buildingCode"3:  {
            "roleID": "3bc21132-079d-4ab9-b9f5-fe2428a281f1",
            "name": "Role 3"
                       },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, I would suggest you change your BCode_Role class as follows

```
public class BCode_Role
{
    [JsonProperty("buildingCode")]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string,object> BuildingCode{get;set;}
    public byte Status { get; set; }
}

public class RoleTable
{ 
    [JsonProperty("roleID")]
    public Guid RoleID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your BuldingDetail Method,

```
public Bcode_Role BuldingDetail()
{
    var result = new BuildingCode_Role();
    var dbBuildingCods = _context.Building.Select(x => x.Code);
    var dbRoles = _context.Role;
    var apiModels = dbRoles.Select(x => x).AsEnumerable().Select((x,index) => new {Key = $"{nameof(BCode_Role1.BuildingCode)}{index}", Value = (object)new RoleTable {RoleID= x.ID, Name = x.Name }}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,y=>y.Value);
    result.BuildingCode = apiModels;
    return result;
}
```

Serializing the result would give

```
{
  "Status": 0,
  "BuildingCode0": {
    "roleID": "0f752579-57cc-4266-a4b4-4759af97525e",
    "name": "Role 2"
  },
  "BuildingCode1": {
    "roleID": "1914a479-cb75-48b9-b5c3-6792acfba7b3",
    "name": "Role 1"
  },
  "BuildingCode2": {
    "roleID": "3bc21132-079d-4ab9-b9f5-fe2428a281f1",
    "name": "Role 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks anu Viswan for this helpful stuff.

Comment: Thanks anu Viswan for this helpful stuff. I Implemeted your code but i got something error like this...                    System.NotSupportedException HResult=0x80131515 Message=Could not parse expression 'value(`1[LearnWebApi.Model.Role]).Select((x, index) => new <>f__AnonymousType1`2(Key = Format("{0}{1}", "BuildingCode", Convert(index, Object)), Value = Convert(new RoleTable() {RoleID = x.ID, Name = x.Name}, Object)))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported      what should i do...? please help it will be much helpful

Comment: @vivekpatel I suspect it might be a case due to EF not support select overload with index. I have updated the answer by converting it to AsEnumerable. Could you please check again

Comment: Actually I think i haven't post with more descriptive because from each Row of Table1:  Bulding Code('BuildingCode0','BuildingCode2') I am looking for respective Role id Detail(roleid , name) from TAble 2(Role Table).   Number of Result of record will be number of rows in table 1. I hope I Will able to describe it. because my english is not well :)  Thanks in Advance :) Please advice on it

Comment: please help me what should i do

Comment: Could u provide with sample? May be as separate question